# JBoss AS 7.1 Remoting JMX Not working

Tags: spring, jboss7.x, rmi, jmx, jconsole

I have an MBean (JMX) which is exposed through RMI in a JBoss AS 7.1 Server but I can't access it. I already follow all of the tutorials revolving around but it just cant work.

This is how I exposed my MBean

```
<bean id="mbeanServer" class="org.springframework.jmx.support.MBeanServerFactoryBean">
    <property name="locateExistingServerIfPossible" value="true" />
</bean>

<bean id="mBeanExporter" class="org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter">
    <property name="beans">
        <map>
            <entry
                key="test:name=foo"
                value-ref="foo" />
        </map>
    </property>
    <property name="server" ref="mbeanServer" />
</bean>

 <bean id="registry" class="org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiRegistryFactoryBean">
    <property name="port" value="1399" />
</bean>

<bean id="serverConnector"
    class="org.springframework.jmx.support.ConnectorServerFactoryBean">
    <property name="objectName" value="connector:name=rmi" />
    <property name="serviceUrl"
        value="service:jmx:rmi://192.168.1.108/jndi/rmi://192.168.1.108:1399/myconnector" />
    <property name="server">
        <ref local="mbeanServer" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

How can I remotely access this in Jconsole ?
I've already tried these:
service:jmx:remoting-jmx://192.168.1.108:9999
service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://192.168.1.108:1090/jmxrmi
service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://192.168.1.108:1090/myconnector

And many more but none of those work.
What am I doing wrong or what should I do ?

Answer (score 1):

On JBoss 7 /EAP6 is can't use rmi for remote jmx calls, JBoss uses `remoting-jmx` protocol for `jmx`.

You can see a full example in: [Using Spring to call jmx bean on JBoss7 / EAP 6](http://nadircode.blogspot.com/2014/08/using-spring-to-call-jmx-bean-on-jboss7.html)

Comment: thanks.. i have be facing this issue for last 3 days.. information given by u is really helpful